# Count occurence of string in an array of string in all document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

All my document in my database (data) have a tags_data :

```
tags_data : [ "am", "gi", "bab", "as", "bru", "dan", "tea", "wec", "fuy" ]
```

So i would like to sort a recap of all tags with the number of occurence for each tag and if possible sort them in an descending sort

I'am trying to do it like this  :

```
db.data.aggregate(
    {$unwind: '$tags_data'},
    {$group: {_id: '$tags_data', sum: {$sum: +1}}}
);
```

Thanks and regards

Comment: doesn't it work?

Comment: i don't know how to sort it so all i have are sum equal to 1 ...

Answer (score 0):

The answer was  :

```
db.data.aggregate(
    {$unwind: '$tags_data'},
    {$group: {_id: '$tags_data', sum: {$sum: +1}} },
    {$sort: {sum: -1}}
);
```

thanks